# Archos 5 IT audio paths in Android

Tags: java, android, audio, archos

I want to import all songs (on the Archos 5 IT) into an array in my app?

How can I do this?

What is the file path?

How do I get an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file management in my archos says it's /storage/Music/

Comment: Well it's still open tbh... No offense but you stated the obvious bit... Not the question. I need an answer still =]